# OCR AWS Textract service fails to make distinction in superscript/exponents

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ocr, amazon-textract

I am working with Textract AWS service.

1. A value like 10<sup>10</sup> is read as 1010. This results in bad data read.
2. Also the bounds of the data within a cell sometimes overlap the bounds of the containing cell.

How to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot fix this yourself. You will have to raise a support ticket and hope they fix it on their side. AWS keeps training their prediction model to make it better. But since their model has been trained with millions of different types of documents, it will lead to mistakes in identifying cells or form elements.

A model that has been specifically trained on only one type of form will perform much better for that form. You have to sacrifice accuracy for diversity.

Comment: It means this has no solution? I can't tune the processing according to my needs? I m quite amazed why have they missed this aspect that a text written in superscript needs to be separated based on the smaller size and position

Comment: No, there is no way to alter the detection capabilities of textract. It is a fully managed AI solution. AWS keeps on training their models with more forms. You can contact support and raise a feature request. If there are many other who want this feature they may decide to train it into Textract in the future.